# How to add comments to post with Mysql and PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I managed to add comments to the table of Comments but it doesn't appear to the related post.  I understand because the foreign key (artID) in the articles table is empty.  How do I fetch the primary key from the articles table?  Here is the structure of my database.

SQL injections issues will be dealt later.  Prepared statements will be done.  I just would like to get some help on the query and php function.  Thank you.

*articles*

   **artID**
   artTitre 
   artAuteur 
   artContenu 
   artDate

*commentaires*

   commentID 
   commentPseudo
   commentText
   **artID**

**commentaires.sql.php**

```
  <?php

  // INSERT
  function insertCommentaire($c){

$PseudoCommentaire = $TexteCommentaire ='';


$PseudoCommentaire = $_POST['PseudoCommentaire'];
$TexteCommentaire = $_POST['TexteCommentaire'];
  $IdArticle = $_POST['IdArticle'];


$qryInsertComm = 'INSERT INTO commentaires (commentPseudo,commentText, artID)
                  VALUES ( \''.$PseudoCommentaire.'\',
                          \''.$TexteCommentaire.'\',
                          \''.$IdArticle.'\')
                         '; 


if (!mysqli_query($c,$qryInsertComm))
{
die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($c));
 }
echo "1 record added";  

}


// UPDATE
function updateCommentaire( $IdCommentaire ){


 }


// DELETE
function deleteCommentaire( $IdCommentaire ){


 }


// CONTROLER //


switch( $action ){

case 'insert' : 

    $process = insertCommentaire($conn);

    if( $process == 'ok' ) 
        header( 'location:index.php?page=home' );
    else 
        $page = 'home';
    break;

case 'update' : 
    $process = updateCommentaire( $_GET[ 'item' ] );    
    if( $process == 'ok' ) 
        header( 'location:index.php?page=home' );
    else 
        $page = 'home';
    break;

case 'delete' : 
    $process = deleteCommentaire( $_GET[ 'item' ] );    
    if( $process == 'ok' ) 
        header( 'location:index.php?page=home' );
    break;
   }

    ?>
```

Comment: There's a lot of code here. Please isolate the issue and post only relevant codes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using a hidden input val called `IdArticle` in

```
<input type="hidden" name="IdArticle" value="" />
```

To keep track of which article the comment should go against, as shown above in the php script:

```
$IdArticle = $_POST['IdArticle'];
```

However, looking at your HTML, you should see that you are passing an empty value to your php script.

To fix this, update your hidden input field like this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="IdArticle" value="<?php echo $rows['artID'] ?>" />
```

Now it should work.

Comment: Please use [`htmlspecialchars`](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars) when outputting to HTML to prevent [XSS](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-site_Scripting_%28XSS%29).

Answer (score 0):

**How do I fetch the primary key from the articles table?**

The same as selecting any other column

```
SELECT `artID` FROM `articles` WHERE `artID` = ?
```

That's the only question I can see in your post.